# Xbox family report for family administrator also

Tags: xbox, microsoft

When we first set up the Xbox user-account and created the Microsoft family account, it was all linked to a single Administrator (family organiser) account.
We never received reports for the Xbox usage, and the MS family profile never showed the Xbox as linked device - presumably because the soul user was the family organiser.
Is there any way to get XBOX usage reports for the family organiser account?

We are getting MS Family reports for other linked devices. Just not the XBOX (Fam Organiser Acc.)

Any ideas?